# javascript cross-domain request iframe VS jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, iframe, cross-domain

I am writing an app that my client uses given javascript, which will collect some HTML data and post to my server.  No data will be returned from my server.

Iframe and Jsonp are two options. I wonder what's the pro and con of each given my situation. Is there any security hole involved in one of them?

another question is how can i identify the user?  say one person copied the javascript and put on his website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonP allows you to get a response, while iframe (for the most part) doesn't.  The security issue with jsonP is that they must trust you not to return malicious javascript, since the "json" returned is really just arbitrary javascript that is essentially eval'd within the  page on their domain. If you were evil, you could steal their customers' cookies or other info and post them back to your server.

Comment: Wait.  What?  How could JSONP expose cookies from another domain?

Comment: @rob updated the question. I wonder if you have an experience on the second part.

Comment: @gilly3 The page on domain A sends a JSONP request to domain B.  This is done by adding a script tag to the document on A, which pulls down a dynamically generated script from domain B.  Domain B sends a script back that has within it a statement that takes document.cookies, packs it into a url on domain B, and adds an image or script tag or the like that the hits domain B with that url.  Now domain B owner just looks at his logs and he has the user's cookies.

Comment: @RuiXia I could make suggestions for the second part of your question, but honestly I think that should just be put in a new question.

Comment: It is interesting that linked scripts are able to read `document.cookie`.  I'd think that the same origin policy would prevent that.